# Github action fails build Typescript but in local machine works

Tags: typescript, react-native, docker, github-actions

I'm using Github actions to build and push a docker container to Azure Repository within a react-native-web application. The strange thing is that in my local Windows 10 machine the build process of the react web app works but in Github Action no. It complains about a Typescript error (the application have been written in TS). Being the build process executed in the same dockerized Ubuntu machine, I thought that the result should always be the same but it's not.

This is my Github action

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Publish Web Client prod

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: publish-web-prod

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # allow to login to azure registry container
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: registryviatek.azurecr.io
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run build and publish web prod
        run: |
          docker build -f ${{ github.workspace }}/src/app/DockerfileGithubProd -t registry.azurecr.io/frontendweb-prod:${{ github.sha }} --no-cache .
          docker push registry.azurecr.io/frontendweb-prod:${{ github.sha }}
```

This is my docker file:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.15.5-alpine as build

RUN apk update
RUN apk add git

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY src/app/package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm install --silent

RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY src/app /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.17.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY src/app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And this is the outout log from Github:

```
Run docker build -f /home/runner/work/App/App/src/app/DockerfileGithubTest -t ***.azurecr.io/frontendweb-test:df0a8964152d2bf50917e59de0af1d2a93e88783 --no-cache .
  docker build -f /home/runner/work/App/App/src/app/DockerfileGithubTest -t ***.azurecr.io/frontendweb-test:df0a8964152d2bf50917e59de0af1d2a93e88783 --no-cache .
  docker push ***.azurecr.io/frontendweb-test:df0a8964152d2bf50917e59de0af1d2a93e88783
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOCKER_CONFIG: /home/runner/work/_temp/docker_login_1617897140374
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.17MB

Step 1/16 : FROM node:14.15.5-alpine as build
14.15.5-alpine: Pulling from library/node
0a6724ff3fcd: Pulling fs layer
3b3c21ce1f8c: Pulling fs layer
560ed84bbbcc: Pulling fs layer
281a19a6c438: Pulling fs layer
281a19a6c438: Waiting
0a6724ff3fcd: Verifying Checksum
0a6724ff3fcd: Download complete
281a19a6c438: Verifying Checksum
281a19a6c438: Download complete
0a6724ff3fcd: Pull complete
3b3c21ce1f8c: Verifying Checksum
3b3c21ce1f8c: Download complete
560ed84bbbcc: Verifying Checksum
560ed84bbbcc: Download complete
3b3c21ce1f8c: Pull complete
560ed84bbbcc: Pull complete
281a19a6c438: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5edad160011cc8cfb69d990e9ae1cb2681c0f280178241d58eba05b5bfc34047
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:14.15.5-alpine
 ---> c1babb15a629
Step 2/16 : RUN apk update
 ---> Running in 25acb5a203e5
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.11.10-8-gf8ac3999ba [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main]
v3.11.10-2-gc655f5d2f5 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community]
OK: 11278 distinct packages available
Removing intermediate container 25acb5a203e5
 ---> 63fdb83b1dfd
Step 3/16 : RUN apk add git
 ---> Running in 2a8874928a55
(1/6) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r2)
(2/6) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.40.0-r1)
(3/6) Installing libcurl (7.67.0-r3)
(4/6) Installing expat (2.2.9-r1)
(5/6) Installing pcre2 (10.34-r1)
(6/6) Installing git (2.24.4-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r2.trigger
OK: 23 MiB in 22 packages
Removing intermediate container 2a8874928a55
 ---> 5bc04a41d9c2
Step 4/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in d5c9efa1b69a
Removing intermediate container d5c9efa1b69a
 ---> 5dbe08ad7bbd
Step 5/16 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in e9066449d147
Removing intermediate container e9066449d147
 ---> 65f6dbf0d570
Step 6/16 : COPY src/app/package.json /app/package.json
 ---> 073aeb43cf5c
Step 7/16 : RUN npm install --silent
 ---> Running in 0ef783dd1abb
Download the file
Download completed!
Extract content
Extract complete!
Delete the downloaded file
added 2188 packages from 1166 contributors and audited 2198 packages in 74.182s

100 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 9 vulnerabilities (6 low, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container 0ef783dd1abb
 ---> b1fbb2e35ceb
Step 8/16 : RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
 ---> Running in 8d1c76d8f6ab
/usr/local/bin/react-scripts -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
added 1618 packages from 748 contributors in 43.313s
Removing intermediate container 8d1c76d8f6ab
 ---> eac5ceccd774
Step 9/16 : COPY src/app /app
 ---> 5bc1cff62d99
Step 10/16 : RUN npm run build:test
 ---> Running in 141e7cf15400

> App@0.0.2 build:test /app
> env-cmd -f .env.staging react-app-rewired build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

/app/src/features/login/login-form/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /app/src/features/login/login-form/index.tsx(38,8):
Type '{ style: { backgroundColor: string; }; icon: string; size: number; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Props, "ref" | "style" | "hitSlop" | "onLayout" | "pointerEvents" | "removeClippedSubviews" | "testID" | "nativeID" | "collapsable" | "needsOffscreenAlphaCompositing" | ... 48 more ... | "icon">': accessibilityComponentType, accessibilityTraits  TS2739

    36 |                        <Image source={require('../../../images/header.png')} resizeMode="center"></Image>
    37 | 
  > 38 |                        <Avatar.Icon style={styles.avatarLockIcon} icon="lock" size={40} color="white"></Avatar.Icon>
       |                         ^
    39 |                        <ViaText type="title" text="Accedi" style={styles.avatarLocktxt}></ViaText>
    40 |                    </View>
    41 |


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ViaVoipApp@0.0.2 build:test: `env-cmd -f .env.staging react-app-rewired build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ViaVoipApp@0.0.2 build:test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-08T15_56_54_595Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build:test' returned a non-zero code: 1

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I know that the error seems right to be raised but if I run `npm run build` or build the container on my local machine, they works.

Comment: The problem was the type definition of react native. Updating @types/react-native to 0.63.52 the problem disppear.